# How to sync frame rate to musical BPM?

Tags: animation

I have a song that is 75BPM and have converted this to one beat every 19.2 frames. I am trying to figure out how to set up an animation in Blender that cycles every 19.2 frames so it will sync with the song. I have tried to play with the settings of the frame rate and time stretching but can't figure out how to make it work (for instance I have set the FPS as 24 and the "Base" as 1.25, which tells me I have a frame rate of 19.2fps, but I can't get a rendered animation to sync with the music).
Any help appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

75 bpm means 75 beats in 60 sec, so it means 1,25 beats per second, so every beat lasts 0.8 sec.

At 25 FPS every frame lasts 1/25 sec, so 1 frame lasts 0.04 sec.

So in a 75 bpm song, every beat lasts 20 frames at 25 FPS (0.8/0.04).